# Por qué getchar en C lee 1 solo caracter, pero en un ciclo while, lee todos los caracteres

Tags: c

no entiendo qué hace la función getchar y por qué lee varios caracteres cuando se usa en un ciclo while

cuando uno usa la función getchar();, la consola te deja escribir todo el texto que quieras, pero al presionar "enter", getchar solo leerá el primer caracter que pusiste, por ejemplo:

```
printf("%d", getchar());

input: abc\n;
output: a
```

pero si haces un ciclo while de esta manera:

```
int c;
while (c = getchar())
    putchar(c);
```

el programa va a leer todo el texto

```
input: abc\n;
output: abc
```

no entiendo por qué lee los demás caracteres automáticamente, si cuando usas getchar sin el ciclo, al leer el primer caracter, se detiene y te deja seguir escribiendo
según mi lógica, con el ciclo, lo que debería pasar es que con cada iteración, en lugar de leer los demás caracteres del texto, debería volver a pedir input del usuario, algo así:

```
abc
> a
def
> d
```

sobre todo si nisiquiera son getchar seguidos
si descompones el ciclo, la lógica del programa es:

```
int c;
c = getchar();

putchar(c);

c = getchar();

putchar(c);
```

por cada getchar que hay, debería volver a pedir input del usuario, tal y como lo hace con el primer ejemplo. No seguir leyendo los demás caracteres del texto que escribiste en la iteración anterior

Comment: probaste leyendo la [documentacion](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getchar-getwchar?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: bueno, estaba leyendo K&R y no entendí, pensé que esa era la mejor documentación

Comment: si si por supuesto!!! el manual original es la mejor de todas... desgraciadamente no se donde esta en la web.... y no lo pusiste en tu pregunta... ;)

Comment: igual.. dice que mueve el puntero de la entrada, no que pide una nueva entrada...

Comment: entonces lo que hace la función es revisar si hay más texto en el buffer de stdin, si hay mas letras, mueve el puntero de la entrada y así sucesivamente hasta que no queden?, y cuando no queden, pedir el input del usuario?

si es así, por qué cuando pones getchar();
escribes "abc", e imprimes lo que retornó (a), y vuelves a poner getchar(); te vuelve a pedir input, en lugar de leer la letra b?

Comment: "no entiendo por qué lee los demás caracteres automáticamente, si cuando usas getchar sin el ciclo, al leer el primer caracter, se detiene y te deja seguir escribiendo" mostra el programa que hace eso.. en realidad, mientras llames a getchar, va a seguir buscando caracteres, no a pedirlos...

Comment: ... tienes razón, no se por qué en mi cerebro pensaba que cada vez que llamabas a getchar, te pedía input, hubiera o no texto en la consola,
lo probé con printf("%c", getchar()); varias veces, y si pones un texto de varias letras, lo lee todo y ya después te pide input

lo que no entendí ahora es que puse printf("%c", getchar()); 7 veces
y probé poniendo esto:
input: a
output: a
input: b
output: b
input: c
output: c
input: d
output: d

pero ahí se paró el programa, y solo puse 4 letras,
getchar tambien lee las letras que pone el propio programa, no solo las del usuario?

Comment: no lo creo, pero no puedo asegurarlo tampoco...

Comment: Yo creo que getchar lee la entra de stdin hasta que consigue el caracter nulo. El por eso que se detenga el while porque si getchar=='\0' el while lo ve como (getchar=0)

Comment: Ejemplo de tu codigo printf("> ");while (c=getchar()) printf("%d\n> ",c);  printf("< %d",c);

Comment: Porque '\0' es lo mismo que 0 por lo que es falso

Comment: probé imprimiendo un texto con printf entre getchar y getchar, y getchar no lee el texto escrito por printf, pero no entiendo entonces por qué si puse 7 printf("%c", getchar());, solo me deja escribir 4 caracteres

Comment: @SantiagoManzanilla No, para la salida hay otro buffer aparte, creo que (stdout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` devuelve un solo caracter de la entrada estándar.

Si se encuentra vacía espera que el usuario ingrese más caracteres. Aquí es donde la cosa se complica.

Normalmente, tanto Windows como Linux esperan hasta el salto de línea para continuar con la ejecución del programa. Así que no es garantía de que obtengas un solo caracter.

Algunos enlaces de interés:

- [High-Level Console Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-modes)
- [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)
- [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798511/13419694)

Answer (score 0):

La función `getchar()` lee solo un carácter a la vez y se cierra con un carácter `\n`, que representa el **EOF** **(**  *end of file* **)**.

Cuando se ingresa *ABCD*, al imprimir solo se imprimirá el primer carácter leído por la función getchar() y el flujo de entrada se cierra con **Enter**.

En el código

```
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  printf("%c", c); // A
```

En el siguiente código, el while sigue ejecutándose hasta que la función `getchar()` devuelva **EOF**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    printf("%c", c);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[*getchar()*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) **no** *acepta strings ni números, lo que hace es leer un carácter de entrada, desde el **teclado**.*

*Está diseñado para manejar caracteres* **individuales** *de la entrada.*
*Cuando presiona* **Enter**, *se finaliza con el carácter de nueva línea.*

Comment: Un pequeño detalle: `/n` no es EOF. De hecho, es una macro y puede que su valor sea `-1`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io

Answer (score -1):

La función `getchar` lo que hace es leer el carácter al que apunta el puntero al archivo de `stdin`.
Ejemplo:

```c
char c=getchar();
printf("El caracter pasado por consola es: %c",c);
```

Porque como dice el nombre de la funcion obtener un caracter.
Para leer la cadena completa puedes usar la función `scanft()` o `fgets`:
Ejemplo:

```c
char input[100];
scanft("%s",input);
printf("Esta fue la entrada \"%s\"",input);
printf("\nFuncion con fgets(): ");
fgets(input,100,stdin);
printf("Salida por fgets: %s",input);
```

¿Como funciona?, asi me imagino como  funciona la función `getchar()`?:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getchar_(){
        char c=0;
        while((c=fgetc(stdin))=='\0');
        return c;
}
int main(void){
        puts("Introduce una palabra");
        char c=getchar_();
        printf("la palabra es: %c",c);
        while ((c=getchar_())!='\n' && c!=EOF) printf("%c",c);
        return 0;
}
```

Sencilla explicación: Mientras el archivo no tenga nada o este vacío el `while` se ejecutará hasta que el usuario ingresé una palabra con salto de línea.

#### ¿Porque la consola al llamar a `getchar` te pide una entrada hasta que presionas `enter`?.

Esto no es por la función `getchar`, sino por una configuración de la consola. La consola por predeterminado te pide entrada hasta que presiones la tecla `enter` y llena el buffer.

> Como es una configuración la podemos cambiar (Pero depende del sistema operativo)

Para sistema basado en `Unix` y `Windows`:
`init_cmd.c`

```c
//para sistema basado en unix.
#ifdef __unix__
#include <termios.h> //termios, TCSANOW, ECHO, ICANON
#include <unistd.h> //STDIN_FILENO
struct termios oldt,newt;
void init_cmd(){
   /*tcgetattr obtiene los parámetros del terminal actual STDIN_FILENO le dirá a tcgetattr que debe escribir la configuración de stdin en oldt*/
   tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
   /*Copiamos la configuración*/
   newt = oldt;
   //CANON normalmente se encarga de que se procese una línea a la vez, lo que significa que regresará si ve un "\n" o un EOF o un EOL y ECHO es para desactivar el eco cuando pulsas una tecla.
   newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO );
   //Esas nuevas configuraciones se establecerán en STDIN. TCSANOW le dice a tcsetattr que cambie los atributos inmediatamente.
   tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
}
#undef RESET
//Restauramos la antigua configuración.
#define RESET() tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
#endif

//Para sistemas basados en Windows.
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
DWORD mode;
HANDLE hstdin;
//Alteramos la consola
void init_cmd(){
    hstdin= GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(hstdin, &mode);
    // Desactiva la bandera ICANON y ECHO
    SetConsoleMode(hstdin, mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT));
}
#undef RESET
//Restauramos los valores originales de la consola.
#define RESET() SetConsoleMode(hstdin, mode);
#endif
```

`main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "init_cmd.c"
int main(void){
    init_cmd();
    char c=0;
    printf("Ver el codigo ANSIC de los caracteres:\nQ para salir\n> ");
    do{
        switch(c){
            case EOF:
            case '\0':break;//Todavía el usuario no ha introducido nada
            default: printf("%c[%d]\n> ",(c!='\n')?c:' ',c);
        }
    }while((c=getchar())!='q' && c!='Q');
    puts("iPresione una tecla para terminar!");
    while((c=getchar())!='\0' && c!=EOF);
    RESET();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pero por qué
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 printf("%c", getchar());
 return 0;
}

solo deja escribir 4 caracteres, el puntero stdin no debería ir sumandose como dices, cada vez que llamas a la función getchar();?, y dejarte introducir 1 caracter por cada llamada

Comment: No confundamos las cosas. `stdin` es un puntero `FILE*`, [una estructura que C utiliza para manipular archivos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/FILE). Aunque sí es probable que el sistema operativo o la librería estándar utilicen un número para identificar la posición actual del archivo.

Comment: @SantiagoManzanilla Me equivoqué, pensé que stdin apunta a una cadena ... Déjame modificar la respuesta

Comment: @Mateo SantiagoManzanilla Listo arregle mi confusión.